# Best solution to encode assets in HaxeFlixel

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxeflixel, lime-haxe

Im trying to find best solution to scramble or encode assets (especially images/textures) for a game written in HaxeFlixel. In the root of my project there is a folder `assets/images`, and that's where are all of my game textures are stored.

If I build the game for desktop, my images stay in this folder.

How can I encode my textures so that after the build nobody can see it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the `embed` attribute of the `assets` node in the project xml file to `true` should accomplish what you want (they will be embedded into the `.exe` file). For example:

```
<assets path="assets/images" embed="true" />
```